# futurebuilder not showing the changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

when I add element to list futurebuilder is not showing the new element until I click on reload button

I tried to use streambuilder but  the list is coming from future function so it gives me an error "future is not a subtype of stream"

```
  body: FutureBuilder(
          future: fun(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Card(
                      child: Text('${snapshot.data[index]['note']}'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Text('');
            }
          },
        ));
```

```
  Future<List<Map>> fun() async {
    List<Map> mylist = await sq.ReadData('SELECT * FROM notes');
    return mylist;
  }
```

```
 Future<List<Map>> ReadData(String sql) async {
    Database? db = await getdb();
    List<Map> response = await db!.rawQuery(sql);
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: future is only a one-time fetch so it cant update unless you refresh it..if you want to see changes in real time you have to create a stream API.

Comment: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 0):

His is FutureBuilder loads data once after initialisation.

To achieve behaviour that you want you have 2 options:

- subscribe on the table changes that will return the Stream(if your Database library supports this)
- rebuild the widget that contain FutureBuilder after you make a change in the table